# Cannot access Django on Google Cloud service through external IP

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

I have started Django server on google cloud service (it's CentOS) successfully:

```html
[root@XXXXXXXXXX]# python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 04, 2022 - 20:20:58
Django version 3.2.12, using settings 'XXX.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And in settings.py of this Django project, I have set ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] to allow all hosts.

But when I try to access this Django project on browser through [external_ip_of_my_google_cloud_compute_engine_instance]:8000 like 35.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000, I keep failing to make it.

I also tried to install uwsgi but the result doesn't change.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I made it finally. Just create a firewall rule for port 8000.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).